# Custom click event getting registered in xDB without triggered by the visitor

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I am trying to register a button click event on a page.  For this I created a custom click event under `/Settings/Analytics/Page events/` and assigned it on a page.
But the problem is: button event gets registered in xDB at session end though the button was never clicked. Looks like Sitecore flushes all the events registered on the page.

I want authors to create custom page events and assign to a page, for example, "CTA Click", "Register Event click", "Learn More click" but register programmatically through javascript click events and avoid other events to flush to xDB.
I am able to call my custom register event from javascript click as below:

```
 function trackClick(){
    var dataValue = { "name": this.getAttribute("name"), "data": this.getAttribute("data"), "text": this.getAttribute("datatext"),"itemId": $('#hidItemGUID').val() };
    var valstring = JSON.stringify(dataValue);
     $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Website/TrackEvents.aspx?query="+valstring,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (data)
                {
            console.log(data);
                }
```

`});`

But I am looking to avoid registering any event which are attached to the page but not necessarily triggered by the visitor.  Any pointers on this?

Also, in xDB I noticed there are page events getting recorded with "Long running request" as the event name. Any clues where does this come from and how can I avoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to trigger a page event while hitting a page, then you shouldn't associate pages with events. Instead your item template could contain a field that defines which page events to trigger on button click. Then *TrackEvents.aspx* will need to find that field and register those page events on the page using `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register()` method.

Regarding "Long Running request" page event, it gets triggered when a request runs longer than specified by *Analytics.LongRunningRequest* setting in *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config* (default value is 5 seconds). It helps to detect pages that need to be optimized and you should not disable it unless you have a good reason for that.